# Hiding the read more div/button/text

Tags: jquery, shorthand

I need some help with hiding a div when a user clicks on it and also sliding down the content of the div that is hidden.The following code is for sliding down the hidden div.

```
    $(document).ready(function (){ $('.hide').hide();
    $('.main:has(".hide")').find('div.toggle').click(function() {
       var el = $(this).next('.hide'),
       check = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.hide').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
    });

    });
```

The above example is [here](http://jsbin.com/isahom/1/edit) and [this link](http://jsbin.com/awirap/3/edit) has the full markup and some experiment that I tried to hide the read more div but it hides every div.Also if someone would help me explain the above if else shorthand statement.

Thanks everyone my query is solved :)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I think you could check `.slideToggle()` function - http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: I need to hide the read more div when a user clicks on it.sliding is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to learn is how to use `this`. 
`this` is a keyword that refers to the element you click on.
So, you can do something like `$(this).hide()` or remove(), or toggle(), or what ever you want.

http://jsbin.com/awirap/5/edit

[JQuery this](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified)

Edit: To show the read more when you click on another you will do this:

`$('.toggle').show();`

You show all of them, and then after this bit of code you do `$(this).hide();` to hide only the one you've clicked on.

Comment: I am sorry but I should have explained it in a better way the first  read more div will hide and when I click on the next read more div it will also hide and the first one will show/unhide.

Comment: I added a new jsbin that has what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot man you saved my day :) can you provide me some info about shorthand if-else statement?

Comment: It's not shorthand, it's literally going to every toggle class and showing them. THEN you turn off the one you click on. 

Unless you're talking about the ternary operator you're using below. This page sums it up nicely: [Ternary Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

The shorthand if/else statement is called the ternary operator.
You code says if the div with the additional text is visible then slide it up (hide), else, slide it down (show). However the part after the : probably shouldn't have ($('.hide').slideUp())

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with your existing script

```
$(document).ready(function (){
       $('.hide').hide();
       $('.main:has(".hide")').find('div.toggle').click(function() {
           $(".toggle").show();
           $(this).hide();
           var el = $(this).next('.hide');
           var check = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.hide').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
       });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this: http://jsbin.com/awirap/6/edit

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('.hide').hide();
   $('.main').find('div.toggle').click(function() {
       if ($('.hide').css("display") == 'none') {
          $('div.toggle',this).addClass("hidden").next().addClass("show");
       } else {    //---------------------------------^^---missed the parentheses
          $('div.toggle').show();
       }
       var el = $(this).next('.hide'),
       check = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.hide').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
   });
});
```

*`if someone would help me explain the above if else shorthand statement.`*

```
(condition) ? if true : if false
```